# Sending foreign characters in c

Tags: c, utf-8, send

I tested this but it won't work. The foreign characters get lost.

```
char message [] = "stringtobesendedwithforeigncharacters도쿄";

t = 39;

while(curler < t) {
    r = send(sockfd, message, t, 0);
    if(r > 0) {
        curler += r;
    }
}
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `char message = "...."` won't compile as it is attempting to assign a `const char*` to `char`. Is that the actual code?

Comment: It does not work because 39 is the number of characters, not the number of bytes in message. And message should be `char *` but I think this is a typo...

Comment: @hmjd if it was `const char *` a declaration like `char *p = "Hello";` would be invalid. The type of a string literal is array N of `char` and the type of the value of a string literal is `char *` and not `const char *`.

Comment: so i know this is not working properly. so how do i get a char * to be sended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `message` declaration and you assign incorrect size to `t` as other guys have already pointed out.

This article will maybe help you: [Unicode in C and C++: What You Can Do About It Today](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html)

Comment: That wont solve my problem right now, but i can learn how to do it with that documentation… thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
char message[] = "stringtobesendedwithforeigncharacters도쿄";
t = sizeof(message)-1;
```

for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Use wchar_t instead of char and functions for this type.